# Foluim - draw circle over choropleth overlay

Tags: python, geopandas, folium

I want to display a map with data in Floium.
For visualization I want to display circles in different kilometer radii as an additional overlay to my choropleth overlay.

Unfortunately, it draws me these circles only under the choropleth overlay and are therefore not visible.

How can I change the position of these?

Many greetings
Leroy

***Working Codeexample***

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from pandas import DataFrame
import folium
import sys

class Class_Map: 
    def __init__(self, Name_GeoJSON, Name_Data):
        self.Name_GeoJSON = Name_GeoJSON
        self.prepareWHMap()

    def prepareWHMap(self):
        """ 2. Prepare data to use the folio libary"""
        # Load GeoJSON
        GeoJSON = gpd.read_file(self.Name_GeoJSON)
        GeoJSON["zip"] = np.nan
        GeoJSON["wh"] = 1
        
        # remove zips in GEOJSON file witch isnt in our own water hardnes database or have errors in th GEOJSON file
        GeoJSON_destatis = GeoJSON["destatis"]
        GeoJSON_zips = list(GeoJSON_destatis)
        zips = []
        for idx in range(len(GeoJSON_zips)):
            try:
                temp_GEO_zip = GeoJSON_zips[idx]["zip"]
                GeoJSON.at[idx, "zip"]  = temp_GEO_zip
                zips.append(GeoJSON_zips[idx]["zip"])
            except:
                print(f"Error in Destatis Data --> no zip for idx {idx}")       
        GeoJSON.dropna(axis=0, subset=['zip'], inplace=True) # delet all data witch doesnt have water hardnes data

        # Make one seperated pandas Filewith zip's and water hardnes data
        JSON_wh = DataFrame(GeoJSON["wh"],columns=['wh'])
        JSON_zip = DataFrame(GeoJSON["zip"],columns=['zip'])
        JSON_zip["wh"] = JSON_wh
        JSON_data = JSON_zip
        
        
        """ 3. Map related map area to water hardness and colorize it via folio to an interactive map """
        m = folium.Map(location=[51, 12],
                   zoom_start=6.5,
                   attr='My Data Attribution')
        
        # add coloring to the map 
        folium.Choropleth(
            geo_data = GeoJSON,
            name="Water Hardness Map",
            data = GeoJSON,
            columns=["zip","wh"],
            key_on = "feature.properties.zip",
            fill_color = 'YlGnBu', 
            line_color = "#0000",
            fill_opacity = 1,
            line_opacity = 0.2,
            legend_name = "Water Hardness",
            smooth_factor=0,
            Highlight= True,
            show=False,
            overlay=True,
            ).add_to(m)   
        
        # Add hover functionality.
        style_function = lambda x: {'fillColor': '#ffffff', 
                                    'color':'#000000', 
                                    'fillOpacity': 0.1, 
                                    'weight': 0.1}
        highlight_function = lambda x: {'fillColor': '#000000', 
                                        'color':'#000000', 
                                        'fillOpacity': 0.50, 
                                        'weight': 0.1}
        NIL = folium.features.GeoJson(
            data = GeoJSON,
            style_function=style_function, 
            control=False,
            highlight_function=highlight_function, 
            tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
                fields=['zip','wh', "GEN","BEZ"],
                aliases=['zip','wh', "GEN","BEZ"],
                style=("background-color: white; color: #333333; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; padding: 10px;") 
            )
        )
        m.add_child(NIL)
        m.keep_in_front(NIL)
        
        # Add dark and light mode. 
        folium.TileLayer('cartodbdark_matter',name="dark mode",control=True).add_to(m)
        folium.TileLayer('cartodbpositron',name="light mode",control=True).add_to(m)
        
        # We add a layer controller. 
        folium.LayerControl(collapsed=False).add_to(m)
        
        m.save("Waterhardness_Map.html")
        
        # Save modified GeoJSON file for faster reuse 
        GeoJSON = pd.DataFrame(GeoJSON)
        GeoJSON.to_pickle("Modified_GeoJSON.txt")
        GeoJSON = gpd.GeoDataFrame(GeoJSON)
        JSON_data.to_csv("JSON_data.csv", header = True)
        self.GeoJSON = GeoJSON
        self.map = m  
            
    def loadWHData(self, Name_GeoJSON):
        """
        Function to load the perpared GeoJSON and Data File. 
        :return: None
        """
        # Load GeoJSON
        GeoJSON = gpd.read_file(Name_GeoJSON)
        self.GeoJSON = gpd.GeoDataFrame(GeoJSON)

                
    def createMap(self):
        """
        Function to create the Map with the prepared Data
        """
        m = folium.Map(location=[51, 12],
                   zoom_start=6.5,
                   attr='My Data Attribution')
        
        folium.Choropleth(
            geo_data = self.GeoJSON,
            name="Water Hardness Map",
            data = self.GeoJSON,
            columns=["zip","wh"],
            key_on = "feature.properties.zip",
            fill_color = 'YlGnBu', 
            line_color = "#0000",
            fill_opacity = 1,
            line_opacity = 0.2,
            legend_name = "Water Hardness",
            smooth_factor=0,
            Highlight= True,
            show=False,
            overlay=True,
            ).add_to(m)
                
        # Add hover functionality.
        style_function = lambda x: {'fillColor': '#ffffff', 
                                    'color':'#000000', 
                                    'fillOpacity': 0.1, 
                                    'weight': 0.1}
        highlight_function = lambda x: {'fillColor': '#000000', 
                                        'color':'#000000', 
                                        'fillOpacity': 0.50, 
                                        'weight': 0.1}
        NIL = folium.features.GeoJson(
            data = self.GeoJSON,
            style_function=style_function, 
            control=False,
            highlight_function=highlight_function, 
            tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
                fields=['zip','wh', "GEN","BEZ"],
                aliases=['zip','wh', "GEN","BEZ"],
                style=("background-color: white; color: #333333; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; padding: 10px;") 
            )
        )
        m.add_child(NIL)
        m.keep_in_front(NIL)
        
        # Add dark and light mode. 
        folium.TileLayer('cartodbdark_matter',name="dark mode",control=True).add_to(m)
        folium.TileLayer('cartodbpositron',name="light mode",control=True).add_to(m)
        
        # add a layer controller. 
        folium.LayerControl(collapsed=False).add_to(m)
        m.save("Waterhardness_Map.html")
        self.map = m 
     
    def CenterfromPolygon(self):
        """
        Function to create the center from the Polygons for each zip. 
        This is nessesary for drawing circles on spezific zip
        :return: None
        """
        self.center = self.GeoJSON.centroid
        
    def addMarkerToMap(self, ZIP:int, meter:int): 
        """
        Function to add an circle into the Map to an spezific location. 
        ZIP = Zip code fore location 
        meter = Radius for circle in Meters 
        :return: None 
        """
        try: 
            idx = np.where(self.GeoJSON["zip"] == ZIP)
            idx = idx[0]
            x = self.center[idx].x
            y = self.center[idx].y
            
            folium.Circle([y,x],
                    radius=meter,
                    popup= ZIP, 
                    fill_color='#000', 
                    weight=2, 
                    color="#000").add_to(self.map)
        except:
            print(f" zip {ZIP} isnt in the water Hardnes Database")
        
    def saveMap(self):
        m = self.map 
        m.save("Waterhardness_Map.html")
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Map = Class_Map(Name_GeoJSON = "Deutschland.geojson", Name_Data = "JSON_data.csv")
    Map.createMap()
    Map.CenterfromPolygon()
    Map.addMarkerToMap(79227, 30000)
    Map.saveMap()
    Map.addMarkerToMap(63863, 30000)
    Map.saveMap()
    sys.exit("Done ... everything is working fine")
```

***Dowloadlink for "Deutschland.geojson"***

you can download an GEOJSON File here. http://opendatalab.de/projects/geojson-utilities/
to get all "zip's" you have to set additional settings for the export data. A i showed in the linked picture.
[Settings for Geojson export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ComtP.png)

Comment: Hi Leroy, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please provide a [mre] that has a code which is able to run. As far as I can see the code you provided needs `import folium` and `import numpy as np` and possibly something else. If you can edit and improve the question according to [ask], I might be able to help you :-)

Comment: Hi, i provided now an working example with the same structure as my own project. I have to delete some parts, but overall it will return the same problem as my own project.